# VBA - Txt file with two delimiters for rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `.txt` file where columns are delimited with `|` (pipe) but rows are delimited with the following string: `_ ~|~ _`

Is there a way to import this by delimiting rows based on the string? If I could just do that, I would be able to do text to columns easily.

This is tricky because the space in each row in Notepad is being exhausted. For example:

```
Policy|Name|Cost _ ~|~ _ 11924|Joe|$20 _ ~|~ _ 154 (end of notepad space)

35|Bob|$40 _ ~|~ _ 18439|Jane|$30 _ ~|~ _ 18492|Ri

chard|$50
```

I need this to read:

```
Policy Name Cost

11924  Joe  $20

15435  Bob  $40

18439  Jane $30

18492 Richard $50
```

and so on. Note that values at the far right are split because notepad has exhausted its line length.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pre-process the text before importing to Excel using a more powerful text editor such as [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com).

In TextPad, do a Replace (F8 key). First let's get rid of your so called "end of notepad space" which I read as line breaks.

Use regular expression to replace double carriage returns "\n\n" with nothing:

[image]

Then, replace pipes "\|" with spaces " ":

[image]

Then, replace "_ ~ ~ _ " with a carriage return "\n":

[image]

This is the final text that should be ready to import into Excel:

[image]

Hope that helps! TextPad is a great tool to have around.

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single step using a VBA macro.

- Read in the entire file to a VBA String variable
- Remove the `newline` characters
- Split on the row delimiter

  - This results in a 1D array
  - Convert the array to a 2D array
  - write the results to the worksheet
  - Do text to columns using the pipe as the delimiter

---

```
Option Explicit
'SET REFERENCE to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Sub ImportSpecial()
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim TS As TextStream
    Dim sFN As Variant
    Dim S As String
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim R As Range

sFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
If Not sFN = False Then
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(sFN, ForReading, False, TristateFalse)

    'Remove the linefeeds
    S = TS.ReadAll
    S = Replace(S, vbNewLine, "")

    'If data is large, will need to transpose manually
    V = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(S, "_ ~|~ _"))

    Set R = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(V), 1)
    With R
        .EntireColumn.Clear
        .Value = V
        .TextToColumns Destination:=R(1), _
                        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                        Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, comma:=False, Space:=False, _
                        other:=True, otherchar:="|"
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
 End If
 End Sub
```

---